# Flutter, persistent Timer

Tags: android, ios, iphone, flutter, dart

I was wondering if someone could help me with something I'm trying to do.

I'm creating a timer (+), I can't make the data persist on the device, ie if I close the app and reopen it, it should show me the value with its progress, like a clock ticking. Is this valid? Will it work in the background? I'm trying to make an unused clock (DateTime.now();), to use in a time attendance application.

I appreciate the time of each one, Thank you... Regards

So far I found the following:
I was wondering if someone could help me with something I'm trying to do.

I'm creating a timer (+), I can't make the data persist on the device, ie if I close the app and reopen it, it should show me the value with its progress, like a clock ticking. Is this valid? Will it work in the background? I'm trying to make an unused clock (DateTime.now();), to use in a time attendance application.

I appreciate the time of each one, Thank you... Regards

So far I found the following:

````
class Timer extends StatefulWidget {
  const Timer({super.key});

  @override
  State<Timer> createState() => _TimerState();
}

class _TimerState extends State<Timer> {
  Duration duration = const Duration();
  Timer? timer;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    startTimer(); // Inicio Reloj
  }

  void addTime() {
    const addSecond = 1;
    if (mounted) {
      setState(
        () {
          final seconds = duration.inSeconds + addSecond;
          duration = Duration(seconds: seconds);
        },
      );
    }
  }

  void startTimer() {
    timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (_) => addTime());
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String twoDigits(int n) => n.toString().padLeft(2, '0');

    final hours = twoDigits(duration.inHours);
    final minute = twoDigits(duration.inMinutes.remainder(60));
    final seconds = twoDigits(duration.inSeconds.remainder(60));
    return Text(
      '$hours:$minute:$seconds',
      style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 30,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
        color: HexColor('#11cdef'), //Celeste
      ),
    );
  }
}```
````

Comment: you may can skip background service, saving on local db and fetching it initState may work fine

Comment: I don't have much experience, I've been on Flutter for 1 year, but you could use shared_preferences. It is for an attendance record, of course, users change the device time when they enter the offline mode, change the device time and send it to me. That's why I thought I would see how to create something similar to the operation of a clock. I appreciate your time :)